# Resolver fails to select dependency version in cargo publish

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

While programs importing `termimad 0.25.4` can compile, they fail to be published with `cargo publish` seemingly because two versions of the `crossterm` import are selected.

`termimad 0.25.4` declares those imports [in its Cargo.toml](https://github.com/Canop/termimad/blob/main/Cargo.toml):

```
[package]
edition = "2021"
resolver = "1"

[dependencies]
coolor = { version="0.6.1", features=["crossterm"] }
crossterm = "=0.23.2"
```

`coolor 0.6.1` imports `crossterm` with this [in its Cargo.toml](https://github.com/Canop/coolor/blob/main/Cargo.toml):

```
[dependencies]
crossterm = { optional=true, version=">=0.23.2" }
```

So it looks to me that termimad should use `crossterm 0.23.2` while coolor users can use any version starting from `0.23.2`.

While would the resolver not just select `crossterm 0.23.2` for termimad ? How to fix that ?

---

Appendix: the Cargo.toml of a program importing termimad 0.25.4 and failing on `cargo publish`:

```
[package]
name = "dysk"
version = "2.8.2"
authors = ["dystroy <denys.seguret@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"
keywords = ["linux", "filesystem", "fs", "lfs", "disk"]
license = "MIT"
categories = ["filesystem", "command-line-utilities"]
description = "give information on mounted filesystems"
repository = "https://github.com/Canop/dysk"
homepage = "https://dystroy.org/dysk"
documentation = "https://dystroy.org/dysk"
readme = "README.md"
rust-version = "1.70"
exclude = ["website", "dysk*.zip"]
build = "build.rs"
resolver = "1"

[dependencies]
dysk-cli = { version = "2.8.2", path = "cli" } # beware: version is also in build dependencies

[build-dependencies]
clap = { version = "4.4", features = ["derive", "cargo"] }
clap_complete = "4.4"
clap_mangen = "0.2.12"
dysk-cli = { version = "2.8.2", path = "cli" }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
toml = "0.7"

[profile.release]
strip = true
```

Comment: I tested this, but the correct crossterm version (e.g. 0.23.2) is selected, but termimad 0.25.4 actually fails to compile for me on macos.

Comment: @frankenapps How does it fail ? Do you use the latest rust ?

Comment: Why for hell does `termimad` use `=`? And why do they use `>=`?

Comment: It fails for me on Windows too with multiple ```the trait bound `crossterm::style::Color: From<coolor::Color>` is not satisfied``` errors.

Comment: "Why for hell does termimad use =? And why do they use >=" : there are breaking changes between versions of this dependency, so it's crucial that termimad uses this specific version of crossterm, while some users of coolor ask for a more recent one.

Comment: Then why the hell there are breaking changes between minor versions of those dependencies?

Comment: It appears Cargo selects two different `crossbeams` versions and of course they're incompatible. That's because in Cargo.toml it specifies not what you linked, but `crossbeam` v0.8. In docs.rs it shows up as well (with `Cargo.toml.orig` being what you linked, but of course ignored), but in GitHub there is no match. Strange...

Comment: Perhaps you used a git repository?

Comment: Or perhaps you used `[patch]` with git, and it is ignored on publish? That could be the reason for the error you're seeing.

Comment: "Then why the hell there are breaking changes between minor versions of those dependencies?" => crossterm is pre 1.0. There are still some research to find the best API so it's totally legit for its author to change it.

Comment: SemVer has a solution for that too. Pre-1.0.0 versions consider minor versions to be potentially breaking, and Cargo respects that.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes. that's why there's this requirement in Cargo.toml. The question is why doesn't the resolver select the right version ?

Comment: Please show your Cargo.toml.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Added it to the question

Comment: Can you show the error output when running `cargo publish`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

If not limited, cargo tends to use the latest version of the dependencies.

`crossterm`'s semantic version is stated as `>=0.23.2`, which means use the latest, if latest is `0.23.2` or anything greater than that, which is currently 0.27.0.

If we try to limit this on parent crate; like setting `crossterm = "=0.23.2"` as `termimad`, intuitively we might expect that resolver will select a common possible version to prevent duplication, but it doesn't, unless they are **SemVer-Compatible**.

Since both stated versions of `crossterm` in `coolor` and `termimad` are **SemVer-Incompatible** then resolver will resolve 2 different crate,`crossterm@0.23.2` and `crossterm@0.27.0` and this will cause conflict between `termimad` and `coolor` on a `crossterm` basis.

---

### Reference

This situation is stated in cargo book as ***unexpected dependency duplication***,
[reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#unexpected-dependency-duplication)

Quote from the reference :

> The resolver algorithm may converge on a solution that includes two
> copies of a dependency when one would suffice. For example:
>
> ```ini
> # Package A
> [dependencies]
> rand = "0.7"
>
> # Package B
> [dependencies]
> rand = ">=0.6"
> ```
>
> In this example, Cargo may build two copies of the rand crate, even
> though a single copy at version 0.7.3 would meet all requirements.
> **This is because the resolver’s algorithm favors building the latest**
> **available version of rand for Package B**, which is 0.8.5 at the time of
> this writing, and that is incompatible with Package A’s specification.
> **The resolver’s algorithm does not currently attempt to “deduplicate”**
> **in this situation**.

---

### Solution

**To Build** : Updating `cargo.lock`, manually or with `cargo update -p crossterm@0.27.0 --precise 0.23.2` will make things compatible with each other and prevent duplication but this will not a solution for publishing case. Each user needs to manage that which is not a desired thing for crates.

**To Publish** : Updating the version requirements, with considering [recommendations in cargo book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#recommendations), some topics regarding this issue:

> ...
>
> - Avoid overly broad version requirements. For example, `>=2.0.0` can pull in any >SemVer-incompatible version, like version `5.0.0`, which can result in broken >builds in the future.
> - Avoid overly narrow version requirements if possible. For example, if you >specify a tilde requirement like `bar="~1.3"`, and another package specifies a >requirement of `bar="1.4"`, this will fail to resolve, even though minor releases >should be compatible.
> - Try to keep the dependency versions up-to-date with the actual minimum versions >that your library requires. For example, if you have a requirement of >`bar="1.0.12"`,
>   and then in a future release you start using new features added in the `1.1.0` >release of “bar”, update your dependency requirement to `bar="1.1.0"`.
>
> ...

Comment: The real solution, in such a case, is to either build 2 crates or versions, or to define their dependencies with features (i.e. coolor will probably come with either `crossterm_0.23` feature or with `crossterm_0_25` feature